# Store and retrieve date of geoproccessing in feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing, metadata, date

I have geo-processing models and scripts that are run on existing feature classes. The models and scripts truncate(delete) the rows in feature classes, and then append new rows. The geo-processing models and scripts are run manually/as-needed by a handful of users. The database is an Oracle Esri.st_geometry geodatabase, and the application is ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

**Is there a way to store the date that the geo-processing model or script is run in the feature class?**

I don't want to store the date in the table name, because the feature class name is referenced by other systems; I wouldn't want the name to be constantly changing. I also need to be able to retrieve the date via some sort of script or query.

Comment: Have a separate table that records the table name, user who ran the model/script, and the date.  Have a calculate run in your model or script that records that info in the new table.

Comment: I think the metadata (via Description tab in ArcCatalog) on a feature class  records geoprocessing performed on the feature class, however I'm not sure if it records everything via every processing means.

Comment: Each geoprocessing tool that creates new output data or updates the input data will add metadata about the execution of the geoprocessing tool, which includes the tool name, its location, and the parameters used. 
Metadata for a dataset is viewed by right-clicking a dataset in the Catalog window or ArcCatalog and choosing Item Description. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm#GUID-3FDAC815-34EE-4CF9-87C7-A787D02C6487

Comment: @BenSNadler  If make your comment an answer, then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Many thanks. Glad it was what you were looking good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each geoprocessing tool that creates new output data or updates the input data will add metadata about the execution of the geoprocessing tool, which includes the tool name, its location, and the parameters used. Metadata for a dataset is viewed by right-clicking a dataset in the Catalog window or ArcCatalog and choosing Item Description 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm#GUID-3FDAC815-34EE-4CF9-87C7-A787D02C6487